# How to implement `Series.map_elements()` with `expression`?

Tags: python-polars

## 1. Data

I have the following `dataframe` created in `polars`:

```py
import polars as pl
data = {"name": ['a', 'b'], "value": ['1-a-2-#', '2-b-3-*']}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌──────┬─────────┐
│ name ┆ value   │
│ ---  ┆ ---     │
│ str  ┆ str     │
╞══════╪═════════╡
│ a    ┆ 1-a-2-# │
│ b    ┆ 2-b-3-* │
└──────┴─────────┘
```

## 2. What I want to do

I'd like to create a new column named `value_new` which contains only the first two "number" elements in the `value` column and they will be separated again by a `-`.

I can do this with a `lambda` function provided to the `.map_elements()` method:

```py
separator = '-'

str_lambda = (lambda name: 
    name.split(separator)[0]
    + separator
    + name.split(separator)[2]
)

df_1 = df.with_columns(
    pl.col('value')
      .map_elements(str_lambda)
      .alias('value_new')
)

print(df_1)
```

Output:

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ name ┆ value   ┆ value_new │
│ ---  ┆ ---     ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ str     ┆ str       │
╞══════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
│ a    ┆ 1-a-2-# ┆ 1-2       │
│ b    ┆ 2-b-3-* ┆ 2-3       │
└──────┴─────────┴───────────┘
```

## 3. My question:

### How to achieve the same using `expression` of `polars`?

I ask this because there is a `warning` in the doc for [polars.Expr.map_elements](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_elements.html) that ***"This method is much slower than the native expressions API"***.

So, I'd like to know how to implememnt the same with `native expressions` that will `identify` and `concat` some elements in a column of `str` data type.

Thanks.

(What I've tried and what I'm expecting are described above.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Polars has its own [`.str.split`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.split.html#polars.Expr.str.split) which is part of the [String API](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/string.html)

It returns a `List` which can be processed using the [List API](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/list.html)

There are various ways to perform this specific task, e.g. you could use [`pl.format`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.format.html#polars.format) to rebuild the string.

```py
df.with_columns(
   pl.format("{}-{}",
      pl.col("value").str.split("-").list.get(0),
      pl.col("value").str.split("-").list.get(2)
   )
   .name.suffix("_new")
)
```

```py
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ name ┆ value   ┆ value_new │
│ ---  ┆ ---     ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ str     ┆ str       │
╞══════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
│ a    ┆ 1-a-2-# ┆ 1-2       │
│ b    ┆ 2-b-3-* ┆ 2-3       │
└──────┴─────────┴───────────┘
```

It could also be done using [regex](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.replace.html#polars.Expr.str.replace):

```py
df.with_columns(
   pl.col("value").str.replace("([^-]+)-[^-]+-([^-]+).*", "$1-$2")
     .name.suffix("_new")
)
```

```py
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ name ┆ value   ┆ value_new │
│ ---  ┆ ---     ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ str     ┆ str       │
╞══════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
│ a    ┆ 1-a-2-# ┆ 1-2       │
│ b    ┆ 2-b-3-* ┆ 2-3       │
└──────┴─────────┴───────────┘
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do

```py
def func(expr: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    expr = expr.str.split(separator)
    return expr.list.get(0) + separator + expr.list.get(2)

df.with_columns(value_new = func(pl.col('value')))
```

which gives

```
shape: (2, 3)
┌──────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ name ┆ value   ┆ value_new │
│ ---  ┆ ---     ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ str     ┆ str       │
╞══════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
│ a    ┆ 1-a-2-# ┆ 1-2       │
│ b    ┆ 2-b-3-* ┆ 2-3       │
└──────┴─────────┴───────────┘
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's the most efficient, but

```py
df.with_columns(
    value_new=pl.col("value")
        .str.extract_all('[^-]')
        .list.gather([0, 2])
        .list.join("-")
)
```